# How to tell atom that a directory includes project source code?

Tags: atom-editor

Atom seems to assume that certain folders are non-project-source folders and thus should not be included in search results and fuzzy finder (cmd+t). I've noticed the following folders are treated this way and the text for these folders are also displayed darker in the file tree:

- `node_modules`
- `lib`
- `log`

That's all fine and dandy, except that I have a `lib` folder that is in fact important project source code that I would like to access via fuzzy finder. Is there a way to instruct atom to include the `lib` folder in fuzzy finder results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Fuzzy Finder* ignores files that are ignored by your VCS (Git in your case?) by default.

You can change that behavior by removing the check on the "Exclude VCS Ignored Paths" checkbox in the general settings:

[image]

In your case, is the `lib` folder part of your `.gitignore` file? If it is, then Atom wouldn't include it in its search results.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I had already checked my `.gitignore` file and when it wasn't there assumed that atom was also ignoring folders not listed there. Of course, it turns out `lib/` was listed in `~/.gitignore_global`. Thanks!